# Clean HTML table, add column from next row value, then delete that row

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

I have scraped a HTML table with rvest into a dataframe, but I need to clean it to suit my needs. I am not sure if I should do this as part of the scrape, or clean it after as part of the data manipulation.

What I need is to add a column to the first row, with the value from the second row. Then delete the second row entirely. Repeat for each odd/even row if that makes sense.

This is how the scrape looks:

```
n = c("Player 1", "Male", "Player 2", "Female") 
s = c(1, "Male", 5, "Female") 
b = c(1, "Male", 5, "Female") 
df1 = data.frame(n, s, b)
```

This is how I'd like it to look:

```
n = c("Player 1", "Player 2") 
s = c(1, 5) 
b = c(1, 5) 
v = c("Male", "Female")
df1 = data.frame(n, s, b, v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
# First, split the dataframe by odd/even rows.
# Then, cbind odd (TRUE) and even (FALSE) rows; 
# only need the first column of every even row because all columns have the same value.

with(
  split(df1, seq_len(nrow(df1)) %% 2L == 1L), 
  as.data.frame(cbind(`TRUE`, v = `FALSE`[[1L]]))
)
```

Output

```
         n s b      v
1 Player 1 1 1   Male
3 Player 2 5 5 Female
```

Comment: This is perfect, easy explanation and worked first time, thank you very much. How can I reset the rows in my new data frame to be 1,2,3,4,5.... instead of 1,3,5,7,9.....?

Comment: Try `row.names(your_new_df) <- NULL` @binga30

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df1 %>% mutate(v = lead(b)) %>% filter(row_number() %in% seq(1,nrow(df1), 2))
         n s b      v
1 Player 1 1 1   Male
2 Player 2 5 5 Female
```

Comment: Another great solution, simple and works exactly as I was after.